# Do i really have to restart the server everytime i made changes?

Tags: php, asynchronous, amphp

i want to use AMP PHP and create a Project. So i started with one of the examples on github and i can see hello world.

Now if i make changes to my code, i have to restart everytime the server. but this is not how it should work right?

Do i have to run some kind of filewatcher which restarts the server everytime i change the code? or should the AMP PHP Server work as Proxy which then call php-fpm instances like an NGINX server would do? If so, can i use the async libraries without the Loop? (since the loop is on server)

How to work the framework? it seems that i understand here something wrong.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to restart the server on changes. You can use a file watcher to do this automatically. PHP doesn't provide a hotreload feature currently.

You can't use cooperative multitasking without a scheduler / event loop, no.